# Converting SQL Server 2012 schema to PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

For a new project we have to export data from a SQL Server 2012 database to a PostgreSQL database.  We have the SQL Server schema but have to create one for PostgreSQL.  As far as possible we would like the schemas to match.  Can anyone give any advice on the best way of converting a SQL Server schema to a PostgreSQL one?  Are there any tools or scripts which will help?  I have seen a PostgreSQL function but to be honest I have no PostgreSQL experience and our remit stops at the data being imported into PostgreSQL so I would like to do everything from the SQL Server side (planning to use SSIS with the 64-bit ODBC driver for PostgreSQL to export the data once we have the schema created)

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your schema people could point out areas which need conversion work?

Answer (score 1):

Although not free, I've used [Toad Data Modeler](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/) for this in the past. We never used it on any particularly complex schemas, but it did do a good job of keeping schemas in sync between various DB platforms.

Your mileage may vary, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Thanks will have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a direct schema converter but most [data modeling tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_modeling_tools) offer such conversion functionality. We use [Dezign for Databases](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/index.html). This tool has got a function "switch target dbms". This a data modeling tool just like Toad Data Modeler mentioned here before. With the database independent modeling functionality you can keep schemas on different db platforms in sync. For data synchronization (data pump) between different database platforms you can use [DataDiff CrossDB](http://www.datanamic.com/datadiff-crossdb/index.html).